# Finding duplicates in one column based on unique values in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have two columns of data, see below:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Email        |       Number     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        email1       |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        email1       |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        email1       |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        email2       |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        email2       |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        email2       |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Can I somehow use conditional formatting to colour the cells where the number column has a duplicate for a unique email? In the table above, the last 2 rows should have their columns colour changed since the number 2 appears two times for the same email.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @CaldeiraG So far I have tried using Conditional Formatting but I have failed in the formula, I can find duplicates in one column but am having trouble comparing it to a unique email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the formatting for A2:B7:

```
=SUM(($A2&$B2=$A$2:$A$7&$B$2:$B$7)*1)>1
```

I concatenate the `A` and `B` columnns and see how many rows match "this" row. The regular result should be `1` - higher values mean duplicates.

[image: Screenshot]